# Appending new data in Richtextbox is changing color of old data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I have one Richtextbox in which I am appending the text with different color say blue color. I want to append blue-colored text in textbox without impacting the content and color of old data.

I am using the following lines of code to obtain the result:

```
private void appendDataInTextBox(string strInterpretableForm, string strCodeForm)
{
    int oldLength = txtBox_InterpretableForm.TextLength;  // at end of text
    string mystring = Environment.NewLine + strInterpretableForm;

    txtBox_InterpretableForm.AppendText(mystring);
    txtBox_InterpretableForm.Select(oldLength, oldLength + mystring.Length); 

    txtBox_InterpretableForm.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

**Now, the problem is that old text of this textbox which had some blue colored text is changing to default color black**. Please help.

Comment: Can you show the code where you change the color of the old text to blue? Because your code sample works for me, it adds blue text and leaves the old text in blue as well.

Comment: This function is called once and then it adds new text in blue color. After which this function is called again which adds new text in blue color but old added text becomes black. No matter how many times I call this function, only latest added substring comes in blue color.

Comment: Still cannot reproduce the problem, when I call this function multiple times the old text keeps it's assigned color.

Comment: What version of .NET framework are you trying this code on?  I have version 4.0 for this application.

Comment: why are you using  txtBox_InterpretableForm.Select(oldLength, oldLength + mystring.Length); there is a txtBox_InterpretableForm.SelectAll() method?

Comment: I am not using SelectAll() because I don't want all the text to be in blue color. Only the appended text in blue color is what is required.

Comment: I tried it with 4.0, 3.5 and even 2.0, but your code still works for me.